# Changed my keyboard layout and now I can't type my password

Tags: keyboard, login

Beginner here. I noticed my keyboard was using different characters and went through a guide indicating how to change keyboard layouts. I thought I chose US correctly. In any case, I rebooted and tried logging in and it was not working. I tried typing the password in the login portion and noticed that when I typed "y" for "raspberry" it would just come out as a square character.

Is there a way to reset the keyboard layout?

Comment: Try typing in the userid box as that is echo'd back to you - so you can see where the letters have moved. You've probably set the layout to Dvorak https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_keyboard_layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attempt to repair problems on the Pi by rebooting to a root shell.

1. Append `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt` and reboot. (This will need to be done on another computer.)
2. After booting you will be at the prompt in a root shell.
3. Your root file system is mounted as readonly now, so remount it as read/write
   `mount -n -o remount,rw /`

You can then edit files.

Running `raspi-config` should let you change keyboard etc.

Comment: I went down a rabbit hole of dpkg-reconfigure, /etc/default/keyboard, and other such things but that "y" character would not come back. I just reinstalled the OS and now everything works and the keyboard layout is even correct. Go figure. Thanks for the help though!